# Getting a specific text/link from the page's source code with chorme extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, magnet-uri

I'm looking for a way i can get a magnet link directly from the source code and opens it on a new tab. Some sites saturate the page with ads, and the solution for this is to use advertsement blocker extensions, the problem is that if you use these extensions on these websites you get unable to get the “magnet:” link, therefore it is still there on the page's source code, i just wold have to copy it from there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Simple solution is to find the element on dev tools (ctrl + f)
2. Use extensions, that can script on a page (run javascript) and use document.querySelector or document.getElementabyTagName